# How can VS Code preserve multiple blank lines in Elixir files after auto-formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code's Elixir formatter removes double (or more) empty lines when formatting the file on save.

Is there an option to leave multiple empty lines untouched, instead of keeping only one empty line between definitions of functions or other blocks?

Comment: Probably one of your extensions is doing it.  Not vscode.  Disable them all and see if it still happens.

Comment: do you use prettier? prettier eliminates blank lines greater than one, and unfortunately it is not configurable. but there are other formaters like beautify that are less strict with white space, including VS codes own built-in defaults.

Comment: You need to look into how that particular (Elixir) formatter is configured - maybe the extension is using some command line tool under the hood for formatting. There isn't really any universal formatting configuration in VSCode that would apply to all languages.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the "Editor end of line" from CRLF to LF